# How to run the “cat” command on the background inside the script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have a USB LTE modem connected to my Raspberry and I need to read replies sent via serial line, generated by requests sent using the "echo" command. Code:

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 > ttyUSB0_logs &
echo "AT+csq" > /dev/ttyUSB0
echo "AT+cgreg=2" > /dev/ttyUSB0
echo "AT+cgreg?" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The problem is, although the "cat" command should run on the background and all output is directed to the file, script still freezes at this point. If I use the first command outside of the script, it works as I expect - it stores all output to the file ttyUSB0_logs on the background and I can use the received data for other operations. The question is - how can I integrate the first command to the script to get it work this way? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using `cat` here? It seems like there should be other tools which are a better fit for your use case.

Comment: Can you please suggest me any better solution? I'm not very skilled in this stuff as it's my school project, so I'd be grateful for any advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remember: in the shell: if you execute all commands one after another, the first command 'cat ....' is still executing even after you executed the last command. 
in a shell script: the 'cat ...' command will be killed soon after executing the last command and therefor could not read and write anymore. For the first step: try to put a "sleep 1" between the commandlines and a longer sleep "sleep 10" after the last command.

Comment: Hi, your idea putting the `sleep 1` commands seems to be working, thanks a lot! But you said, the `cat` command should be terminated when the script ends, anyway I can still see it running after the script is done, I have to kill it manually with `kill #process`, or `fg` and ctrl+c. Is there any possibility to kill the process automatically after the script ends?

Comment: No, if you can do a **fg**, the cat process was not executed from the script, but executed in your shell.

---
#!/bin/bash
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 > ttyUSB0_logs &
echo "AT+csq" > /dev/ttyUSB0
echo "AT+cgreg=2" > /dev/ttyUSB0
echo "AT+cgreg?" > /dev/ttyUSB0
---

Comment: my comment before was not ready  - this one is ok
---
No, if you can do a **fg**, the cat process was not executed from the script, but executed in your shell.
if your script looks like:


`vi ~/myscript
#!/bin/bash
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 > ttyUSB0_logs &
sleep 1
echo "AT+csq" > /dev/ttyUSB0
sleep 1
echo "AT+cgreg=2" > /dev/ttyUSB0
sleep 1
echo "AT+cgreg?" > /dev/ttyUSB0
sleep 10
#END
`
---
execute as:
`~/myscript`
should work - with no cat process open.

Comment: sorry cant format it right now:

Comment: sorry cant format it right now: –

Answer (score 0):

In modems, the AT part of the command string was for detecting baud rate, parity, etc.  The device timed the serial data to measure the bit widths

To do that, it needed an idle timeout to establish the start of the "A"

Your script could be blasting them out too fast

Try putting a sleep in front of each command line

The was an S register that held the timeout time.  It has been a while, so I forget which.  2 seconds I think was typical

Comment: Note that this is over USB.

Comment: Admittedly.  But sometimes SoC based devices will use a USB to serial chip driving a UART on the SoC inside the box.   That used to be a quick way to market, especially if you didn't want to worry about drivers.

Comment: I have no idea if the pi has minicom ported to it.  But using that as a terminal program on the pi might be an easier way to explore the device than echo statements